# Unity - Draw Path for Characters to follow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) Characters in path moving from the start of path to the end of it.

My tries:

```
public class EnimaySpwan : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public Transform WaterSpawn; // this where I want my enemy appear 

    private void Update() 
    {
        Instantiate (gameObject, WaterSpawn.position, WaterSpawn.rotation);
    }
}
```

My object movement script:

```
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed;

    private void Start() 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * speed;
    }
}
```

This code makes character move in direct way, not in the specific path I draw as I want.

### Problems:

I need to create path for my enemies from start of a path (Instantiation) position to end of path (destination).

How can I approach this, any help?

Comment: Can you add more details please? What exactly is wrong? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly - you want to spawn an enemy in point A and make it move to point D through points B and C (or any other kind of path). Try placing empty objects on your terrain then:

1. Spawn enemy
2. Get `transform.position` of points B and C in your path.
3. Keep updating transform.position of the enemy till it gets to B then to C and finally to D. etc

Or you could use a `NavMesh`. Here is a tutorial explaining how to implement a Nav Mesh Agent: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/navigation/navmesh-agent

Comment: Please don't add "naked" links, but give a short explanation of what the link is about.

Answer (score 2):

Using iTween editor is the easiest way to do this without much programming skill. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84